# I hold a (art.10 2004/38/ce) residence permit from Italy, do i need to apply for another one in Ireland?

Tags: italy, ireland, family, freedom-of-movement, residence-permits

I'm a non-EEA national, a spouse of EEA, and I hold a residence permit under the article 10 2004/38/ce, we entered Ireland without any problems, my question is, do I have to apply for an Irish Residence Permit?

Comment: What do you want to do in Ireland? Does your EEA spouse intend to establish there with you?

Comment: How long do you plan to stay in Ireland?  If "indefinitely" then this question belongs on [Expatriates.SE].  Otherwise, the answer is probably "no," but not necessarily.  Details matter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you must apply for an Irish **residence card** (Article 10) to replace your Italian **residence card** if your spouse intends to stay longer than 3 months.

> [EU Treaty Rights - Immigration Service Delivery (Ireland)](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-join-family-in-ireland/joining-an-eea-or-swiss-national/eu-treaty-rights/)
> **Freedom of movement**
> You **cannot** use a ‘residence card of a family member of a union citizen’ that has been issued by another member state to authorise your long-term stay in Ireland. Your residence card must be issued by the Irish authorities.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was very helpful